# Modify navbar dom in a clean way in MEAN.IO

Tags: mean.io

I am using MEAN.IO to creating my application. Right now, I want to move Join menu from right to left. I can do so by modify `packages/system/server` directly, but it is not a very clean way. I wonder what is the clean way for me to achieve it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's some html markup hardcoded in **/packages/system/public/views/header.html**, try to change the css class of:

```
<div class="account"></div>
```